# Splitting row entries at 10th character and adding a tab using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have row entries like the following in a file:

```
10120000522012000060
10120000522012006544
10120000522012054444
....
```

and I want to transform the entries into

```
1012000052  2012000060
1012000052  2012006544
1012000052  2012054444
..
```

splitting the entry after the 10th character and inserting tab there.
Is there a quick way to do it sed/awk? My file is 5GB and it is taking too long in python.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help debugging your own `bash`, `awk` or `sed` code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43645803/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` which should be a lot faster than your python script:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{10})/\1\t/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,10) "\t" substr($0,11)}' file
1012000052      2012000060
1012000052      2012006544
1012000052      2012054444
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
cat infile | tr -d '\t\n\r\f ' | sed 's/.\{10\}/& /g' > outfile
```

take care of space at end of td string.

It will first remove all whitespaces and then add them each 10 characters.

Edit. You may want to add other whitespaces also...

Answer (score 1):

Or perl:

```
perl -pE 's/(.{10})/$1\t/'
```

also, **much** faster as regex solution:

```
perl -pE 'substr($_,10,0) = "\t"'
```

benchmarks:

```
#sed regex
yes 10120000522012000060 | head -10000000 | time sed -E "s/^(.{10})/\1\t/" >/dev/null
7.38 real         7.34 user         0.03 sys

#same in perl
yes 10120000522012000060 | head -10000000 | time perl -pE 's/^(.{10})/$1\t/' >/dev/null
11.56 real        11.37 user         0.11 sys

#perl substr
yes 10120000522012000060 | head -10000000 | time perl -pE 'substr($_,10,0) = "\t"' >/dev/null
2.52 real         2.40 user         0.07 sys
```

**clear winner** :)

Comment: You do not need both -n and -p. -p is enough :) Also, my sed times are way less and comparable to the perl.

Comment: @jm666 would you mind adding the awk (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43647748/1745001) timing to your answer just for completeness? It seems to be a bit slower than the perl version on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="10 10"}{print $1,"\t"$2}' file 

1012000052  2012000060
1012000052  2012006544
1012000052  2012054444
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the original file,you can use this:

```
sed -i -E "s/(.{10})/\1\t/" data
```

If you want to create another file,you can use this:

```
sed -E "s/(.{10})/\1\t/" data > new_data
```